# Elixir GenServer handle_cast function not found

Tags: elixir

I'm new to Elixir so this is probably something really simple but I couldn't find the answer to this.

So I have a simple GenServer like this:

```
defmodule BlobStorageActor do
  use GenServer

  def start_link do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, name: __MODULE__)  
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, %{}}
  end

  def lookup(server, name) do
    GenServer.call(server, {:lookup, name})
  end

  def cp(pid, container, file_path) do
    GenServer.cast(pid, {:cp, container, file_path})
  end

  def handle_cast({:cp, container, file_path}, state) do
    %{body: containers} = ExAzure.request!(:list_containers)

    unless Enum.any?(containers, &( {:blob_container, container, _, _, _ } = &1)) do
      ExAzure.request(:create_container, [container])
    end

    ExAzure.request(:put_block_blob, [container, String.replace(file_path, " ", "_"), File.read!(file_path)])
  end
end
```

But when I do this:

```
iex(53)> iex(4)> BlobStorageActor.cp(pid, "test", "Doxie 0008.pdf")
BlobStorageActor.cp(pid, "test", "Doxie 0008.pdf")
iex(53)> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in GenServer.cast/2
iex(53)>     (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:630: GenServer.cast({:ok, #PID<0.8023.0>}, {:cp, "test", "Doxie 0008.pdf"})
iex(53)> iex(4)> BlobStorageActor.cp(pid, "test", "Doxie 0008.pdf")
BlobStorageActor.cp(pid, "test", "Doxie 0008.pdf")
iex(53)> ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in GenServer.cast/2
iex(53)>     (elixir) lib/gen_server.ex:630: GenServer.cast({:ok, #PID<0.8023.0>}, {:cp, "test", "Doxie 0008.pdf"})
```

Why do I get this error?

```
FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in GenServer.cast/2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're passing `{:ok, pid}` instead of just `pid`.

Comment: Well, thats right.  Thanks, that was so obvious I should have seen that from a mile away.

Comment: Also since your naming the `GenServer` with `__MODULE__` (which is not recommended) you can also do something like:

`GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, {:cp, container, file_path})`

But looking up the server by name instead of pid is a little but slower, in case this would be called a lot.